# postgresql query in comparing dates with duration stored in other column

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have a table like

```
------------------------------
id | created_date | duration 
------------------------------
```

duration is no.of days, now I want to select records that are `created_date(timestamp)+duration(integer) > current time`

I tried this in my where clause

```
 "select * from table where (created_date + duration days) > now()"
```

now resultset is empty, I have records that should come out for my requirement, I suspect my query is not right, help me get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very close.  I would do this as:

```
select *
from table
where created_date > now() - duration * interval '1 day'
```